# Moving file with wildcard and add timestamp to the file name

Tags: files, filesystems, timestamps, mv, move

I need to move a file to an archive folder, and add a timestamp in front of the file name.

```
mv /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv 
/dev/DataStage/myProject/Archive/TEST/MyFile_*.csv
```

moved MyFile_20180817.csv as My~1.csv instead of MyFile_20180817.csv

When I move the file to the archive folder, I also need to add a time stamp in the front of the file name, for example: MyFile_20180817.csv to 20180817_1057.MyFile_20180817.csv:

```
mv /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv 
/dev/DataStage/myProject/Archive/TEST/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`.MyFile_*.csv
```

moved MyFile_20180817.csv as 201808~1.CSV instead of MyFile_20180817.csv

Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be an individual timestamp for each and every file, or would one single stamp calculated upfront do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. shorter with rename (it will fail in case of different Filesystems):

   rename '' "/dev/DataStage/myProject/Archive/TEST/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`." /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv
2. with loop

   for file in /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv ;
   do
       filename=`basename $file`
       mv $file /dev/DataStage/myProject/Archive/TEST/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`.${filename}
   done

Comment: Thank you
I tried the shorter rename, and it gave me this error: 
rename: renaming /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_20180730.csv to 
/dev/DataStage/myProject/Archive/TEST/20180817_1450./dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_20180730.csv failed: No such file or directory
. So it looks like it appends "/dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/" to the new file name.

Comment: When using the loop, I get the error "sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Comment: Stack exchange broke code pasting. Try this: https://pastebin.com/7keRSd8C